# Error al capturar la imagen de la cámara con GStreamer en Python

Tags: python, linux, gstreamer, opencv

Necesito implementar [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) con [GStreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/), pero no hallo la forma de escribir con openCV sobre una tubería de GStreamer.

La idea es tomar la imagen de la webcam a través de OpenCV y procesar algunos filtros pero con GStreamer.

También quiero decirle al `VideoCapture()` que tome los datos desde `v4l2src device=/dev/video1` , o en su defecto que lo escriba en `v4l2src device=/dev/video0` (uso linux, y tengo un disp de video virtual, video0)
me arroja el siguiente error:

> GStreamer: cannot find appsink in manual pipeline  in function
>   cvCaptureFromCAM_GStreamer

Éste es mi código:

```
import cv2

cv2.namedWindow('webCam')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)  # "v4l2src device=/dev/video1"
# cap.open("img/bg.avi")


if cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
else:
    ret = False
    print "problema aqui?"


while True:
    #se toma cada frame
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame,1)

    cv2.imshow('webCam', frame)

    width = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
    height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
    # cv2.imwrite("/dev/video0", frame)
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m','p','4','v')
    pathVid = "/dev/video0" # 'img/output2.avi'
    # out = cv2.VideoWriter(pathVid, fourcc, 30, (width,height))
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(pathVid, fourcc, 30, (640,480))
    out.write(frame)
    cv2.VideoWr
    esc = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == 27
    if esc:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

¿revisaste los valores de **FPS**?

usa un **FPS** compatible entre la captura y la escritura, 30 yo creo es muy alto, parte por valores más bajos, igual que para el tamaño (640x480).

EL codec también puede estar generando un problema, revisa los codecs para tu plataforma: http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php
considera que hay combinaciones de fps, codec, y tamaño que se saben funcionan para ciertas plataformas, suerte!